# "all them", "all of them" "them all". May I use any of them in this phrase?

Tags: word-in-context

"Can you see that row of barriers in the cinder track? Well, you may find it difficult to believe, but I could jump 'all them' / 'all of them' / 'them all', even the highest ones, when I studied here."

Although one of them may be considered the "correct" one, may the other ones still be used as an alternative or should they be completely discarded?

Comment: "all them" is the only one that sticks out to me as clearly wrong, though you may hear someone say it in the American South.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"All of them" and "them all" are both perfectly acceptable and, according to ngram, are nowadays about equally prevalent. My personal experience, however, is that "them all" is used in US speech only for emphasis.

"All them" is not educated language in the US. What would be said instead is "all those __."